# BugSnag, Django and the before_notify callback

Tags: django, bugsnag

BugSnag's documentation suggests this for custom fields:

```
def callback(notification):

    # if you return False, the notification will not be sent to
    # Bugsnag. (see ignore_classes for simple cases)
    if isinstance(notification.exception, KeyboardInterrupt):
        return False

    # You can set properties of the notification and
    # add your own custom meta-data.
    notification.user = {"id": current_user.id,
      "name": current_user.name,
      "email": current_user.email}
    notification.add_tab("account", {"paying": current_user.acccount.is_paying()})

# Call `callback` before every notification
bugsnag.before_notify(callback)
```

my application is JWT token based internl-api application server. Meaning, I don't have a `current_user` or any users "logged in" for that matter. Is there any way to get to the user of the current request? in views it's available as `request.user` after the JWT middleware parses out the token but how do I apply it here into this callback? I don't have access to the request object? `notification.request` doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation?

Comment: https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/python/customizing-error-reports/

Comment: do you know where `current_user` is coming from? I don't see it being defined anywhere

Comment: Me neither.  But that's besides the point. My question is how do I get, in that callback, the last user that authenticated via JWT tokens

Comment: That's what I am trying to help you with. If you know where `current_user` is being defined, you can override it, correct? To get `current_user`, they used the `request` object, most probably.

Comment: Probably but how do I gain access to the last request made from within this callback?

Comment: From the [source code](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-python/blob/master/bugsnag/django/__init__.py#L14) I see that you can get access to request like this: `request = notification.request_config.django_request`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if my POST was a flat list of keys and values, this is how I got the `email` value.

```
d = dict(notification.request_config.django_request.POST)
print(d['email'][0])
```